# Browser view is missing on the view results tree

Tags: jmeter

Browser view is now missing on the view results tree of jmeter.  How do I revert it? As i was running a test the browser view listener cant be found anymore.

[image]

Comment: I am able to see it in version 5.1.1 and 3.2. Check if it is unavailable for all http request or some specific. Try to download or extract a fresh copy and check if something is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’re using OpenJDK or Oracle JDK > 10, It’s related to missing JavaFx library.

You need to use Oracle JDK 8 which embeds it.